# How to fix this syntax error in MPLABX IDE?

Tags: assembly, syntax, pic, mplab

I am a beginner to PICs and I want to make the LED light up.
However, every time I want to build the code, it returns a syntax error. I am unsure of what the syntax error actually is for since I have copied the syntax of the datasheet.

I am using MPLABX IDE v6.15, with XC8 compiler v2.41.

[Please let me know of any further information you would like?]

My entire assembly code:

```
list p=16f84A ;PIC used is PIC16f84A
#include <xc.inc>
__CONFIG _CONFIG1, _CP_OFF & _WDT_OFF & _XT_OSC & _PWRTE_OFF
;__CONFIG _CONFIG1 & H'3FFF'& H'3FFB' & H'3FFD' & H'3FFF'
;CP OFF, WDT OFF, XT_OSC[crystal required], PWRTE OFF
BSF 03h, 1 ;03h = STATUS
MOVLW 00000 ;All pins are output
MOVWF 85h ;TRISA
BCF 03h,1 ;Back to Bank 0
MOVLW 00010 ;W, bit 1 pin is high
MOVWF 05h ;Move 00010 into PortA register
;LED should now light up
```

Previously I have tried using #include "p16f84a.inc", in order to use STATUS, TRISA, PORTA etc however that returned an error saying the file was not found, therefore I switched to using the register memory addresses e.g. 03h and that has removed that error.

Currently my output screen returns this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.41\pic-as\bin\pic-as.exe" -mcpu=PIC16F84A -c \
-o build/default/production/TurnLEDOn2.o \
TurnLEDOn2.asm \
  -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.15/packs/Microchip/PIC16Fxxx_DFP/1.4.149/xc8"  -msummary=+mem,-psect,-class,-hex,-file,-sha1,-sha256,-xml,-xmlfull -fmax-errors=20 -mwarn=0 -xassembler-with-cpp
TurnLEDOn2.asm:3:: error: (876) syntax error
make: *** [build/default/production/TurnLEDOn2.o] Error 1
(908) exit status = 1
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:110: recipe for target 'build/default/production/TurnLEDOn2.o' failed

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 660ms)
```

The line being flagged for Syntax Error is:
`__CONFIG _CONFIG1, _CP_OFF & _WDT_OFF & _XT_OSC & _PWRTE_OFF` however I am unsure what the syntax error in this line is.

Therefore, I would be grateful if someone could highlight any issues in my program so I can fix it and hopefully then have the code build successfully.

Thank you

Comment: Just guessing here, but `p16f84a.inc` may very well be the place where `__CONFIG` is also expected to be defined, so if you don't have that...

Comment: Your assembly format is for an older version assembly compiler which can be compiled using one of the compilers *MPASM* or *GPASM*. The newer compiler which comes integrated to XC8 C compiler however, has a slightly different format. This is the format that @GJ. has used in his/her answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your code is a lot of mistakes...
Try something like...

```
processor 16F84A 
    
#include <xc.inc>
    
radix       dec         ;default are decade numbers

PSECT code
 
; CONFIG
  CONFIG  FOSC = XT     ; Oscillator Selection bits (XT oscillator)
  CONFIG  WDTE = OFF    ; Watchdog Timer (WDT disabled)
  CONFIG  PWRTE = OFF   ; Power-up Timer Enable bit (Power-up Timer is disabled)
  CONFIG  CP = OFF      ; Code Protection bit (Code protection disabled)
 
 
code:
    BSF     STATUS, 5   ;Select memory Bank 1
    MOVLW   0b00000     ;All pins are output
    MOVWF   TRISA       ;TRISA
    BCF     STATUS, 5   ;Back to Bank 0
    MOVLW   0b00010     ;W, bit 1 pin is high
    MOVWF   PORTA       ; Move 00010 into PortA register
Loop:
    nop
    goto Loop
    
END code
```

Comment: In order to switch between *BANK 0* and *BANK 1*, the **5th** bit of the `STATUS` register should be modifed not the 1st one. Alternatively the predefined `RP0` identifier can be used. `BSF STATUS, 5` or `BSF STATUS, RP0`.

Comment: @Kozmotronik: right, I have made just a copy/paste of his code. OK I have repair the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your assembly code style looks old *MPASM* style which is obsolete as of MPLABX IDE v5.40. While the new compiler is **pic-as** compiler, the new style is a little different than the old style assembly.
Beginning with the configuration, the old style was changed from

```
__CONFIG _CP_OFF & _WDT_OFF & _XT_OSC & _PWRTE_OFF
```

to

```
CONFIG  FOSC = XT             ; Oscillator Selection bits (RC oscillator)
CONFIG  WDTE = OFF            ; Watchdog Timer (WDT disabled)
CONFIG  PWRTE = OFF           ; Power-up Timer Enable bit (Power-up Timer is disabled)
CONFIG  CP = OFF              ; Code Protection bit (Code protection disabled)
```

Note that your config statement is not correct even for the old style.

There are also some changes on how the register and bit names defined and how the inclusion is made. It is not needed to include the specific chip model name anymore since it is done automatically when you select the chip model for your project and add `#include <xc.inc>` line in your source code.

When it comes to the register and bit name definitons, while register names hasn't changed, however microchip has added a new pattern for the bit definitions. The new bit number definition pattern is `[REGISTER NAME]_[BIT_NAME]_POSN` or `[REGISTER NAME]_[BIT_NAME]_POSITION`. Therefore the new `RP0` style is `STATUS_RP0_POSN` or `STATUS_RP0_POSITION`. The usage along with its register is as following:

```
bsf    STATUS, STATUS_RP0_POSN
```

However, when I have a look at the *.inc file I see that the `RP0` is defined as a bank masked bit setting macro like `#define RP0   BANKMASK(STATUS), 5`, means that you can directly use it with bit instructions without specifying the containing register as following:

```
BSF    RP0
```

With all those said, your final fixed code would be as following

```
; PIC16F84A Configuration Bit Settings

; Assembly source line config statements

; CONFIG
  CONFIG  FOSC = EXTRC          ; Oscillator Selection bits (RC oscillator)
  CONFIG  WDTE = OFF            ; Watchdog Timer (WDT disabled)
  CONFIG  PWRTE = OFF           ; Power-up Timer Enable bit (Power-up Timer is disabled)
  CONFIG  CP = OFF              ; Code Protection bit (Code protection disabled)

// config statements should precede project file includes.
#include <xc.inc>

PSECT code
 
 code:
    bsf     STATUS, STATUS_RP0_POSN ; Switch to bank 1
    clrf    TRISA   ; Set all PORTA bits as output
    bcf     STATUS, 5   ; or bcf    RP0, switch to bank 0
    bsf     PORTA, 1    ; or bsf    RA1, set the 2nd bit of PORTA
    
main:
    sleep   ; Halt infinitely
    goto main
    
END
```

**Post Tip**
You don't have to write config code manually, instead you can use the MPLAB's configuration code generator tool. In order to generate config statements in MPLABX IDE select **Window > Target Memory Views > Configuration Bits** from the menu. A new panel named *Configuration Bits* will appear below and lets you select configuration. Once you select the appropriate configuration for your project click **Generate Source Code to Output** button. The *Output* panel will show up with the generated configuration codes. Just copy and paste it in the upper side, above your code and that's it.